# Artifacts when draw particles with some alpha

Tags: opengl, shaders, opengl-es, blending

I want to draw in my game some particles. But when I draw one particle above another particle, alpha channel from this above "clear" previous drawed particle. 
I set in OpenGL blend in this way:

```
glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
```

My fragment shader for particle is very simple:

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
uniform sampler2D u_maps[2];
varying vec2 v_texture;
uniform float opaque;
uniform vec3 colorize;
void main()
{   
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_maps[0], v_texture);
    gl_FragColor.rgb = texColor.rgb * colorize.rgb;

    gl_FragColor.a = texColor.a * opaque;
}
```

I attach screenshot from this:
[image]

Do you know what I made wrong ?

I use OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the z sorting.

Try not writing to the z-buffer when rendering your particles using :

```
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
```

And don't forget to reset it to GL_TRUE after that.

Comment: thx, it's work ;)